# Integrability of Fourier transform under growth condition

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Suppose that $\Psi$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is absolutely integrable, continuously differentiable, and has integral zero. Also, assume
$$ |\Psi(x)|+|\nabla \Psi(x)|\leq (1+|x|)^{-(n+1)}$$
Does Fourier inversion hold for $\Psi$?

I think the answer is yes, and since $\Psi$ is in $L^1$, it suffices to show that its Fourier transform is absolutely integrable. I tried using the inequality
$$1\leq C(1+|x|)\sum\limits_{|\beta|\leq 1}|x^{\beta}|$$
which eventually led to the pointwise inequality
$$|\hat{\Psi}(x)|\leq C(1+|x|)\left|[(1+|\cdot|)^{-(n+1)}]^{\land}(x)\right|$$
and don't see how to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For $n=1 $ then $\Psi \in L^2, \Psi' \in L^2$ implies $(1+|\xi|)\hat{\Psi} \in L^2$ so that $\hat{\Psi} \in L^1$, for $n \ge 2$ it doesn't hold and you may have $\hat{\Psi } \not \in L^1$. What do you mean exactly with "the Fourier inversion holds" ?

Comment: Fourier inversion means that the Fourier inverse transform of the Fourier transform of $\Psi$ is equal to $\Psi$ almost everywhere. A common sufficient condition is to check that $\hat{\Psi}$ is in $L^1$.

Comment: How do you define the Fourier transform for non-$L^1$ functions... Under suitable definitions the Fourier inversion theorem holds in $L^2$ and even in the space of tempered distributions.